# Using UserDialogs in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm stucked with usage of plugin Acr.UserDialogs in android app, based on MVVMCross.
In PCL project i used IUserDialog in viewmodel constructor injection.

I have installed Acr.UserDialogs package both in PCL and in Droid project, but when i run app, it throws:

> In android, you must call UserDialogs.Init(Activity) from your first
>   activity OR UserDialogs.Init(App)  from your custom application OR
>   provide a factory function to get the current top activity via
>   UserDialogs.Init(() => supply top activity)

I tryed to call in my viewModel:

```
UserDialogs.Init(this);
```

But Init is not recognized
And calling of UserDialogs.Instance.Loading ().Hide(); in app throws the same issue.

How it should be initialized in android project?

> **Upd:** Final solution to workaround this looks like:
>
> 1. In PCL project App.cs add: Mvx.RegisterSingleton(() =>
>      UserDialogs.Instance);
> 2. In Your first loaded activity in OnCreate
>          add: UserDialogs.Init(() => this);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This error is very clearly. You can't initialize it in viewModel, You can only do that in your main activity.

FAQ

> > I'm getting a nullreferenceexception when using loading.
>
> This happens when you run loading (or almost any dialog) from the
>   constructor of your page or viewmodel. The view hasn't been rendered
>   yet, therefore there is nothing to render to.

Android Initialization In your **MainActivity**

```
UserDialogs.Init(this);
OR UserDialogs.Init(() => provide your own top level activity provider)
OR MvvmCross - UserDialogs.Init(() => Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTopActivity>().Activity)
OR Xamarin.Forms - UserDialogs.Init(() => (Activity)Forms.Context)
```

[GitHub docs.](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs)